# Capturing Macros in Scheme

Tags: macros, scheme, racket, define-syntax

What's the simplest way to define a capturing macro using `define-syntax` or `define-syntax-rule` in Racket?

As a concrete example, here's the trivial `aif` in a CL-style macro system.

```
(defmacro aif (test if-true &optional if-false)
    `(let ((it ,test))
        (if it ,if-true ,if-false)))
```

The idea is that `it` will be bound to the result of `test` in the `if-true` and `if-false` clauses. The naive transliteration (minus optional alternative) is

```
(define-syntax-rule (aif test if-true if-false)
    (let ((it test))
       (if it if-true if-false)))
```

which evaluates without complaint, but errors if you try to use `it` in the clauses:

```
> (aif "Something" (displayln it) (displayln "Nope")))
reference to undefined identifier: it
```

The [`anaphora` egg](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/anaphora) implements `aif` as

```
(define-syntax aif
  (ir-macro-transformer
   (lambda (form inject compare?)
     (let ((it (inject 'it)))
       (let ((test (cadr form))
         (consequent (caddr form))
         (alternative (cdddr form)))
     (if (null? alternative)
         `(let ((,it ,test))
        (if ,it ,consequent))
         `(let ((,it ,test))
        (if ,it ,consequent ,(car alternative)))))))))
```

but Racket doesn't seem to have `ir-macro-transformer` defined or documented.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Racket macros are designed to avoid capture by default. When you use `define-syntax-rule` it will respect lexical scope.

When you want to "break hygiene" intentionally, traditionally in Scheme you have to use `syntax-case` and (carefully) use `datum->syntax`.

But in Racket the easiest and safest way to do "anaphoric" macros is with a [syntax parameter](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxparam.html) and the simple `define-syntax-rule`.

For example:

```
(require racket/stxparam)

(define-syntax-parameter it
  (lambda (stx)
    (raise-syntax-error (syntax-e stx) "can only be used inside aif")))

(define-syntax-rule (aif condition true-expr false-expr)
  (let ([tmp condition])
    (if tmp
        (syntax-parameterize ([it (make-rename-transformer #'tmp)])
          true-expr)
        false-expr)))
```

I wrote about syntax parameters [here](http://www.greghendershott.com/fear-of-macros/Syntax_parameters.html) and also you should read Eli Barzilay's [*Dirty Looking Hygiene* blog post](http://blog.racket-lang.org/2008/02/dirty-looking-hygiene.html) and [*Keeping it Clean with Syntax Parameters* paper (PDF)](http://www.schemeworkshop.org/2011/papers/Barzilay2011.pdf).

Comment: TBH, the blog post is not really relevant since the paper covers it more nicely and with more examples...

Comment: @EliBarzilay Although I wanted to include the blog post for anyone who might be "OMG PDF!" or "OMG Research Paper!", I agree the paper is best.

Comment: Yeah, I know that some people have that reaction -- it's just that the beginning parts in that paper are very accessible...  But yeah, it does make a little value in having just a blog post...

Comment: It's broken: `(let ((it 'BAD)) (aif 'show-it (displayln it) 'other-thing))` displays `BAD` instead of `show-it`. The macro fails to capture `it`. What you're doing instead is relying on the equivalent of a global variable.

Comment: @ThrowawayAccount3Million As the last paragraph [here](http://blog.racket-lang.org/2008/02/dirty-looking-hygiene.html) explains: "The resulting macro does not break hygiene. For example, `(let ([it 3]) (if #t it))` evaluates to `3`, because it shadows the global `it` that `if` changes. This is a change from a real unhygienic macro — but that's the whole point: we (the macro author) do not interfere with scopes in the user code."

Comment: @GregHendershott So you and Eli are already aware that it's broken. That doesn't mean it's not broken. Sometimes we *want* to interfere with scope. That's the whole point of capturing macros. As it happens, since my previous comment I've found a way to write a real capturing macro in Racket that involves walking down the syntax tree and stripping the scope (via `datum->syntax` composed with `syntax->datum`) from any identifier that has the same name as the one you want to capture.

Comment: When you truly need capture, or want capture for the sake of capture, you can use `datum->syntax` as I'd mentioned. With it, all things are possible, good or bad. But to back up: I wouldn't use `aif` for real code. I think a better idea would be something like `if-let`, where you supply the id. Usually it's clearer and more-dependable when users of the macro supply the identifier. (Obviously there are exceptions like `struct`, but at least that introduces names prefixed by a user-supplied id.)

Comment: [Example `if-let`](https://github.com/greghendershott/rackjure/blob/master/rackjure/conditionals.rkt#L10-L12).

Comment: I agree that it's *usually* clearer and less bug-prone not to inject bindings into the scope of a user's code. In fact, that's easily 99% of the time. But I don't agree with the extremes to which R6RS has gone in this regard, where even the word `else` in a `cond` or `case` form is a bound identifier that `cond` can't see if there's a local binding named `else`. Every now and again you run into a situation where it's more convenient to be able to inject an identifier, and IMO `aif` is one of those cases. I'd have no qualms with using it in production code.

Answer (score 4):

See Greg Hendershott's macro tutorial. This section uses anaphoric if as example:

http://www.greghendershott.com/fear-of-macros/Syntax_parameters.html

Comment: Or better yet, see [Greg Hendershott's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20055079/1281433). :)

Comment: In which Greg Hendershott ultimately refers to Eli Barzilay's blog post and paper... thank goodness we have tail elimination... :)

Answer (score 2):

Although the answer above is the accepted way to implement aif in the Racket community, it has severe flaws. Specifically, you can shadow `it` by defining a local variable named `it`.

```
(let ((it 'gets-in-the-way))
     (aif 'what-i-intended
          (display it)))
```

The above would display `gets-in-the-way` instead of `what-i-intended`, even though `aif` is defining its own variable named `it`. The outer `let` form renders `aif`'s inner `let` definition invisible. This is what the Scheme community wants to happen. In fact, they want you to write code that behaves like this so badly, that they voted to have my original answer deleted when I wouldn't concede that their way was better.

There is no bug-free way to write capturing macros in Scheme. The closest you can come is to walk down the syntax tree that may contain variables you want to capture and explicitly strip the scoping information that they contain, replacing it with new scoping information that forces them to refer to your local versions of those variables. I wrote three "for-syntax" functions and a macro to help with this:

```
(begin-for-syntax
 (define (contains? atom stx-list)
   (syntax-case stx-list ()
     (() #f)
     ((var . rest-vars)
      (if (eq? (syntax->datum #'var)
               (syntax->datum atom))
          #t
          (contains? atom #'rest-vars)))))

 (define (strip stx vars hd)
   (if (contains? hd vars)
       (datum->syntax stx
                      (syntax->datum hd))
       hd))

 (define (capture stx vars body)
   (syntax-case body ()
     (() #'())
     (((subform . tl) . rest)
      #`(#,(capture stx vars #'(subform . tl)) . #,(capture stx vars #'rest)))
     ((hd . tl)
      #`(#,(strip stx vars #'hd) . #,(capture stx vars #'tl)))
     (tl (strip stx vars #'tl)))))

(define-syntax capture-vars
  (λ (stx)
     (syntax-case stx ()
         ((_ (vars ...) . body)
          #`(begin . #,(capture #'(vars ...) #'(vars ...) #'body))))))
```

That gives you the `capture-vars` macro, which allows you to explicitly name the variables from the body you'd like to capture. `aif` can then be written like this:

```
(define-syntax aif
  (syntax-rules ()
       ((_ something true false)
        (capture-vars (it)
           (let ((it something))
            (if it true false))))
       ((_ something true)
        (aif something true (void)))))
```

Note that the `aif` I have defined works like regular Scheme's `if` in that the else-clause is optional.

Unlike the answer above, `it` is truly captured. It's not merely a global variable:

```
 (let ((it 'gets-in-the-way))
     (aif 'what-i-intended
          (display it)))
```

### The inadequacy of just using a single call to `datum->syntax`

Some people think that all you have to do to create a capturing macro is use `datum->syntax` on one of the top forms passed to your macro, like this:

```
(define-syntax aif
  (λ (stx)
     (syntax-case stx ()
       ((_ expr true-expr false-expr)
        (with-syntax
            ((it (datum->syntax #'expr 'it)))
            #'(let ((it expr))
                (if it true-expr false-expr))))
       ((_ expr true-expr)
        #'(aif expr true-expr (void))))))
```

Just using `datum->syntax` is only a 90% solution to writing capturing macros. It will work in most cases, but break in some cases, specifically if you incorporate a capturing macro written this way in another macro. The above macro will only capture `it` if the `expr` comes from the same scope as the `true-expr`. If they come from different scopes (this can happen merely by wrapping the user's `expr` in a form generated by your macro), then the `it` in `true-expr` will not be captured and you'll be left asking yourself "WTF won't it capture?"

You may be tempted to quick-fix this by using `(datum->syntax #'true-expr 'it)` instead of `(datum->syntax #'expr 'it)`. In fact this makes the problem worse, since now you won't be able to use `aif` to define `acond`:

```
(define-syntax acond
    (syntax-rules (else)
        ((_) (void))
        ((_ (condition . body) (else . else-body))
         (aif condition (begin . body) (begin . else-body)))
        ((_ (condition . body) . rest)
         (aif condition (begin . body) (acond . rest)))))
```

If `aif` is defined using the `capture-vars` macro, the above will work as expected. But if it's defined by using `datum->syntax` on the `true-expr`, the the addition of `begin` to the bodies will result in `it` being visible in the scope of `acond`'s macro definition instead of the code that invoked `acond`.

### The impossibility of really writing a capturing macro in Racket

This example was brought to my attention, and demonstrates why you just can't write a real capturing macro in Scheme:

```
(define-syntax alias-it
  (syntax-rules ()
     ((_ new-it . body)
      (let ((it new-it)) . body))))

(aif (+ 1 2) (alias-it foo ...))
```

`capture-vars` cannot capture the `it` in `alias-it`'s macroexpansion, because it won't be on the AST until after `aif` is finished expanding.

It is not possible at all to fix this problem, because the macro definition of `alias-it` is most probably not visible from the scope of `aif`'s macro definition. So when you attempt to expand it within `aif`, perhaps by using `expand`, `alias-it` will be treated as a function. Testing shows that the lexical information attached to `alias-it` does not cause it to be recognized as a macro for a macro definition written out of scope from `alias-it`.

Some would argue that this shows why the syntax-parameter solution is the superior solution, but perhaps what it really shows is why writing your code in Common Lisp is the superior solution.

Comment: Downvoting not because of the silly flamewar you're trying to get into, but because it is just not an answer to the original question.  There are three fundamental problems in your answer (and maybe in your understanding).  This will be long so I'll split it into several comments.

Comment: (A) Yes, using a syntax parameter means that the binding can be shadowed -- the reason that this *is* desirable is that the `it` syntax parameter is viewed not as a global, but as *part of the `aif` macro* -- so shadowing `it` is equivalent to shadowing `aif`, and that will (obviously) break it.  (Note btw that `it` should be defined wherever `aif` is defined -- which means that it's as global as `aif` which, in racket, usually means that it's defined in some module (ie, it's still not "global").)  This means that your criticism of syntax parameters is misplaced.

Comment: (B) Your "writing a real capturing macro is impossible" conclusion is wrong.  You can probably fix it by first expanding the input forms (eg, use `local-expand`).  Doing that won't be new though: see the text on syntax parameters which mentions stripping all lexical information (and CL not keeping it in the first place).  Also see Racket's `define-macro` which makes the simple CL-like `aif` definition work fine, and it should also work when used in `acond` and even with `alias-it`.  (`define-macro` is doing what you're essentially trying to do, only in a more organized and methodical way.

Comment: (C) Finally, the main problem is, again, that it's really not answering the question.  If you really insist on this direction, point people at `define-macro` and be done with it.  As for your long post, you should look into this more, phrase it better, and post it somewhere where such discussions are proper.  The Racket mailing list is one such place -- and if you stick to the details instead of being offended, the result is surely going to be better.  SO is just not a good place for such discussions, by design.  This is also why these "comment-discussions" are hard to do, so I'll stop here.

Comment: I'll look into it more, but I've had problems getting `define-macro` to do this kind of thing in the past, which is why I didn't mention it. The same kind of problems I mentioned in the answer, where the macro works only as long as it's not part of another macro. I gave up on it back when lists were still mutable.

Comment: Regarding the appropriateness if this site as a forum, I don't see anybody talking about capturing macros anywhere but here, and I'm only writing about them because the subject came up.

Comment: One possible problem wrt these macros is if you want to combine them with regular ones.  My guess is that in case of macros-using-macros you'll want the whole chain done with `define-macro`.  As for the discussion, there have been countless such discussions, on newsgroups, mailing lists, and blogs.  The whole anaphoric macros thing is a very well chewed-up subject.  That also applies to the realization that `it` is much better considered part of the anaphoric macro syntax rather than a new name that the macro injects, which makes syntax parameters work so well.